# Broadcast operation between arrays of shape (N, M) and (N,)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is a rather simple question but I can't seem to find the answer. Consider two simple arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (2, 1000))
b = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (2,))
```

I want to perform the operation `a - b` so that the final array is `([[a[0] - b[0], a[1] - b[1]])` and I get

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,1000) (2,)
```

How can I perform this (or some other) operation?

Comment: The automatic expansion is to the left, not the right, e.g. (2,) to (1,2).  To go the other direction you have be explicit.

Comment: try `(a.T - b).T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [General Broadcasting Rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules):

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes
>   element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its
>   way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1

So there's the error because the last dimension of `a` (1000) and `b` (2) can not be broadcasted; You can convert `b` to a 2d array of shape `(2, 1)` so that `1` -> (can broadcast to) `1000`, `2` -> (can broadcast to) `2`:

```
a - b[:,None]                            
#array([[ 0.06475683, -0.43773571, -0.62561564, ...,  0.05205518,
#        -0.1209487 ,  0.16334639],
#       [ 0.58443617,  0.28764136,  0.75789299, ...,  0.18159133,
#         0.28548633, -0.12037869]])
```

Or

```
a - b.reshape(2,1)
```